# Foreign keys with Code First in a Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

Very simple question but it looks like I'm trying to implement a simple one-to-many relationship between two models.

So far, what I have is this :
A product class :

```
public class Products
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public long Code { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateModified { get; set; }
    public Boolean Reviewed { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("BundleId")]
    public int BundleId { get; set; }
    public virtual Bundles Bundle { get; set; }
}
```

And the Defects class looks like this:

```
public class Defects
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public String Description { get; set; }
    public String Picture { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ProductId")]
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public Products Product { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual Users User { get; set; }
}
```

I thought that I did not need to add an `ICollection` of `Defects` to the `Products` class because it's a "simple" one-to-many relationship and this code would be enought to be able to get the ID of a Product in the `Defects` class (I don't need more).

But, of course I get an exception :

> The property 'ProductId' cannot be configured as a navigation property. The property must be a valid entity type and the property should have a non-abstract getter and setter

How may I solve that issue ?
I might be doing someting wrong with my two foreign keys but since I declared the name of the foreign keys, I assumed it would have been enought.

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: If you have to add collection to your database model, why not do this? What the problem here?

Comment: Do I have to ? I thought it was just two different implementations.
So I need to keep the same code and add collections to the parent models, is that it ?

Comment: Think you have to, but to ensure, pls, read docs https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj713564(v=vs.113).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what your relationship can be distilled to.
Please note that ForeignKey annotation is applied to navigation property with the name of the key property.

If you build one-to-many relationship - then ICollection is absolutely necessary.
 Otherwise where's the "many"

```
   public class Products
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public virtual List<Defects> Bundle { get; set; }
    }


    public class Defects
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }


        public int ProductId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("ProductId")]
        public Products Product { get; set; }
    }
```

FK can also be applied to the key property. But in that case you have to put the name of the instance of related class there

```
    public class Defects
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }


        [ForeignKey("Product")]
        public int ProductId { get; set; }


        public Products Product { get; set; }
    }
```